# Remove items that have the same value from an array "a". Remove an item with the same index of the one removed from "a" in an array "b"

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this problem. I'm plotting a temperature chart and I have two arrays:

**a** that contains the registered temperature value during the day. e.g.:

a=[22.1, 23.4, 21.7,...];

and **b** that contains the registered time when that temperature happened during the day. e.g.:

b= ["2016-12-15 16:50","2016-12-15 16:55","2016-12-15 17:00",...]

They are related! so if I take the value of

a[2]

that's the value of the temperature registered at the time of

b[2]

### Now that's what I want to do:

I would like to "merge" the values that are similar so if I have in the **array a** at index 3,4,5,6,7 something like 22.1, 22.1, 22.1, 22.1, 22.1 I want to merge them all into a supercool and only one 22.1 at the index 3 of my **array a**. Then I want to remove all the item from **array b** that have index 4,5,6,7.I also want to keep the **array a** and  **array b** order. This is only an example, I don't want to always remove item indexed from 4 to 7.

Comment: Did you have a question?  Are you stuck on some specific part of this task? If so, where?

Comment: Yeah,
First I'm stuck in removing item with similar value. 
Second I can't see how to remove the to remove all the item from array b that have the same index as the one removed from array a.

Comment: Sorry I'm kinda of an "advanced array noob".

Comment: `Array.prototype.reduce()` then.

Comment: OK for array A and array B you want to merge but give us the expeted result you want

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand the question. But perhaps, you could build a array of objects on the basis on arrays A and B. each object would have a property time and value of the temperature like this :

```js
var a = [22.1, 23.4, 21.7 ,22.1];
var b= ["2016-12-15 16:50","2016-12-15 16:55","2016-12-15 17:00", "2016-12-15 17:05"];
var temperatures = a.map((x,i) => ({"values": x, "time": b[i]}));
console.log(temperatures);
```